# Horizontally center MatDialog with 100% width and fixed maxWidth

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I am trying to horizontally center a MatDialog with fixed width:

```
let dialog = this.dialog.open(EditVisitPopupComponent,
  { data: { visit: this.visit }, width: '100%', maxWidth: '500px' });
```

For some reason, adding the `width` parameter adds an inline `justify-content: flex start` to the parent overlay while I'd like it to stay `justify-content: center`.

I know the way of creating modals that consists in creating a `Overlay` and injecting a component into it. But I don't understand why I can't do it simply by using `MatDialog`.

What I've tried:

```
let dialog = this.dialog.open(EditVisitPopupComponent,
      { data: { visit: this.visit }, position: this.overlay.position().global().centerVertically().centerHorizontally(), width: '100%', maxWidth: '500px' });
```

But the types do not match.

I also tried with `backdropClass` and a sibling CSS selector, but I didn't get the wanted result.

What am I missing? Is there any way to configure the `Overlay` of a `MatDialog`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having tried to use the material internal class `MatDialogContainer` for my own purpose, I managed to get rid of `MatDialog` and I was able to create my own dialog with parametrable `Overlay` where I put `position: this.overlay.position().global().centerVertically().centerHorizontally()`.

But I got the exact same result!

Then I read [GlobalPositionStrategy](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/position/global-position-strategy.ts) source code, and I figured out that Angular Material contributors did not consider the `width: 100%; max-width:...px;` use case since there's an ugly

```
if (config.width === '100%') {
  parentStyles.justifyContent = 'flex-start';
}
```

Then i rollbacked to the `MatDialog` solution and I put `width: 'calc(100%)'`, which, even if ugly, works like a charm and finally got me the expected result.

**Update v9.1.0 (01-2020)**

This bug has finally been fixed, some logic has been added (based on `width` and `maxWidth`) to determine what `align-items` and `justify-content` should contain. More details on the concerned commit: https://github.com/angular/components/commit/9f2c93725e973e2c76e3308a72c5bd14f5ec483c

Comment: I found out the why.  Inside the overlay code it has this line: styles.marginLeft = config.width === '100%' ? '0' : this._leftOffset; which obviously kills centering.  The calc(100%) avoids the match.  As would 100.0% silly, but it works.

Comment: You weren't wrong, was just adding details since I was confused why it was doing that.  Plus I know in a year I'll run into this again and find this again. :)

Comment: Awesome answer even tho its a little hacky. I think unless the material team change their code this is probably the best solution.

Comment: @TimothyLouw yeah it's hacky but I have no choice since there are design warts in Angular material :(

Comment: Genius, perfect simple solution to a design flaw of Angular material.

Comment: Also, this issue has been fixed in https://github.com/angular/components/commit/9f2c93725e973e2c76e3308a72c5bd14f5ec483c

Comment: @frunkad thanks for pointing out, will check this and update my answer